# How to pass multiple data and display it in a different fragment as a custom scrollable list in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a waste management app. There are two fragments that I need to modify, AddFragment and LogsFragment. in AddFragment, there are 5 input boxes; 2 spinners (location and type of waste) and 3 EditTexts (name of waste, amount of waste, and waste quantity). I need to modify it so that when I press the input button in the AddFragment, the data that I inputted will be displayed chronologically (latest input on the top) as a custom list which I already have the separate xml layout file in logs_container.xml. Once the button is pressed each time, there should be an instance of the logs_container LinearLayout stacking on top of each other, a history log of the data inputs.

Note that the logs_container should be inside of the parentLayout LinearLayout in fragment_logs.xml.

Here are my codes:

AddFragment.kt:

```
class AddFragment : Fragment() {

@SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val binding = FragmentAddBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    val uid = arguments?.getString("uid")
    
    val itemsLocation = listOf(
        "Building 1",
        "Building 2",
        "Building 3"
    )

    val adapterLocation = ArrayAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        R.layout.spinner_selected_item2,
        itemsLocation
    ).apply {
        setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.style_spinner)
    }

    binding.locationPickerInput.adapter = adapterLocation

    val wasteType = listOf(
        "Hazardous Waste",
        "Residual Waste",
        "Recyclable Waste",
        "Food Waste"
    )

    val adapterWaste = ArrayAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        R.layout.spinner_selected_item2,
        wasteType
    ).apply {
        setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.style_spinner)
    }

    binding.wastePickerInput.adapter = adapterWaste

    binding.wastePickerInput.onItemSelectedListener =
        object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                val selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                when (selectedItem) {
                    "Hazardous Waste" -> {
                        binding.wasteQuantity.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.nameOfWaste.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.amountOfWaste.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    "Residual Waste" -> {
                        binding.wasteQuantity.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.nameOfWaste.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.amountOfWaste.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    "Recyclable Waste" -> {
                        binding.wasteQuantity.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.nameOfWaste.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.amountOfWaste.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    "Food Waste" -> {
                        binding.wasteQuantity.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.nameOfWaste.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.amountOfWaste.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }

    binding.inputButton.setOnClickListener {
        val name = binding.nameEditText.text.toString()
        val amount = binding.amountEditText.text.toString()
        val quantity = binding.quantityEditText.text.toString()
        val location = binding.locationPickerInput.selectedItem.toString()
        val wasteType = binding.wastePickerInput.selectedItem.toString()

    }

    return binding.root

}
```

LogsFragment.kt:

```
class LogsFragment : Fragment() {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private lateinit var spinnerLocation: Spinner
    private lateinit var itemsLocation: List<String>

    private lateinit var datePickerDialog: DatePickerDialog
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private lateinit var datePickerButton: Button

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logs, container, false)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        spinnerLocation = view.findViewById(R.id.locationPickerLogs)!!

        itemsLocation = listOf("Building 1", "Building 2", "Building 3")

        val adapter1: ArrayAdapter<*> = ArrayAdapter<Any?>(
            requireContext().applicationContext,
            R.layout.spinner_selected_item,
            itemsLocation
        )

        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.style_spinner)

        spinnerLocation.adapter = adapter1

        initDatePicker()
        datePickerButton = view.findViewById(R.id.datePickerLogs)
        datePickerButton.text = getTodaysDate()

        datePickerButton.setOnClickListener {
            datePickerDialog.show()
        }

    }

    private fun initDatePicker() {
        val dateSetListener =
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, year, month, day ->
                var month = month
                month = month + 1
                val date: String = makeDateString(day, month, year)
                datePickerButton.setText(date)
            }

        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        val style: Int = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT

        datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(view?.context!!, style, dateSetListener, year, month, day)

    }

    private fun makeDateString(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int): String {
        return getMonthFormat(month) + " " + day + " " + year
    }

    private fun getMonthFormat(month: Int): String {
        if (month == 1) {
            return "JAN"
        }
        if (month == 2) {
            return "FEB"
        }
        if (month == 3) {
            return "MAR"
        }
        if (month == 4) {
            return "APR"
        }
        if (month == 5) {
            return "MAY"
        }
        if (month == 6) {
            return "JUN"
        }
        if (month == 7) {
            return "JUL"
        }
        if (month == 8) {
            return "AUG"
        }
        if (month == 9) {
            return "SEP"
        }
        if (month == 10) {
            return "OCT"
        }
        if (month == 11) {
            return "NOV"
        }
        if (month == 12) {
            return "DEC"
        }

        return "JAN"
    }

    private fun getTodaysDate(): String {
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        var month: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        month = month + 1
        val day: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        return makeDateString(day, month, year)
    } }
```

fragment_add.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LogsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Logs"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logs"
            android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            >

        <Spinner
                android:background="@drawable/spinner1"
                android:id="@+id/locationPickerLogs"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                />

        <Button
                style="?android:spinnerStyle"
                android:text="JAN 01 2020"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:id="@+id/datePickerLogs"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    >


            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_logs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LogsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Logs"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logs"
            android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            >

        <Spinner
                android:background="@drawable/spinner1"
                android:id="@+id/locationPickerLogs"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                />

        <Button
                style="?android:spinnerStyle"
                android:text="JAN 01 2020"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:id="@+id/datePickerLogs"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    >


            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

logs_container.xml (This is the custom template):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/logsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/status_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User#DUMMY"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        />

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/locationText"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationLog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/typeText"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/typeOfWaste"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nameText"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameOfWaste"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/amountText"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amountOfWaste"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/quantityText"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wasteQuantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a shared `ViewModel` to store your data. That way `AddFragment` can pass new data to the VM as it's added, and that can append that data to a list in a `LiveData` object (as well as persisting the data to disk etc. if required). Your `LogsFragment` would just `observe` that `LiveData` and update as new data comes in. You'd honestly be better using a `RecyclerView` to display items (you can reverse the order if you want newest on top) and have your observer just update its `Adapter` with the new list, but it's up to you